# Select count from multiple tables and group by

Tags: mysql, count

Help me!

```
$sql = SELECT `id`, `email`, `avatar`,`fullname`,
            SUM(result) as sum_result,
            SUM(total) as sum_total,
            COUNT(rank)  as `top_1` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 1, 
            COUNT(rank)  as `top_2` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 2,
            COUNT(rank)  as `top_3` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 3
GROUP BY userid_created
ORDER BY sum_result DESC, sum_rate DESC
LIMIT 0, 100';
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 1,

Comment: Start by adding a `FROM` clause.  Then you can work on fixing the rest of the syntax.

Comment: $sql = SELECT `id`, `email`, `avatar`,`fullname`,
            SUM(result) as sum_result,
            SUM(total) as sum_total,
            COUNT(rank)  as `top_1` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 1, 
            COUNT(rank)  as `top_2` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 2,
            COUNT(rank)  as `top_3` where `itq_exam_thread_test`.`rank` = 3   FROM  `itq_exam_thread_test` GROUP BY userid_created
ORDER BY sum_result DESC, sum_rate DESC
LIMIT 0, 100'; BUT NOT RUN

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` is a clause for the entire query, not a modifier in the `SELECT` clause.  What you want is conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, doing the count is quite easy, because it treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context.  So, you can just use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT id, email, avatar, fullname, SUM(result) as sum_result,
       SUM(total) as sum_total,
       SUM(rank = 1) as top_1,
       SUM(rank = 2) as top_2,
       SUM(rank = 3) as top_3
FROM itq_exam_thread_test
GROUP BY userid_created
ORDER BY sum_result DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

I removed `sum_rate` from the `ORDER BY`, because it is not defined.

Comment: Thank you! but not run. Photo description results    http://imgur.com/9oOQIoJ            and      http://imgur.com/aEuVjMX

Comment: @QuangChucDoan . . . Try setting up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: SQL Fiddle:http://i.imgur.com/t2eMaNa.png                        http://www.mediafire.com/download/5slxg5ligdze887/itq_exam_thread_test.rar

Comment: @QuangChucDoan . . . SQL Fiddle is at www.sqlfiddle.com.